# How to get objects from database django?

Tags: python, django

I have a little problem.

I'm trying to use django filter e.g. `SomeTable.objects.filter(someParam="something")` 
this is working well but...

What if i have param name like string in some variable like: `test="someParam"`.

How to now call filter function? I tried `SomeTable.objects.filter(eval(test)="something")` but seems not working...

Answer (score 3):

Because [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter)  arbitrary number of arguments using **kwargs this should work:

```
test="someParam"
SomeTable.objects.filter(**{test: "something"})
```

Comment: Just another thing... How to call __iexact function on that parameter?

Comment: Try: SomeTable.objects.filter(**{test + '__iexact': "something"})